# Single Model Multi-Step Forms with Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, workflow, state-machine

I'm trying to do a multi-step form with ActiveRecord persistance.

So first the user submit a form and a "user" is created.

Later, an admin review that "user", and could 1) reject that user or 2) ask for more information.

Then another form is generated for the user to provide the new information.

And so on.

It's much like an state-machine, but none of the gems available have clear documentation. Also, I guess I'm relying on custom defined actions for the controller.

Don't know if my design is bad or if there's some correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what is the right way of doing it, but in my project I did it by adding a status field to the user model. So, for example:

- status = 0 - new user
- status = 1 - admin rejected that user
- status = 2 - admin asks for more informations

Then you have to generate correct forms for a user based on a status field. You can do it in the controller:

```
def multistep_form
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  case @user.status
  when 0
    render "form_1"
  when 1
    render "rejected"
  when 2
    render "form_2"
  else
    render "error"
  end
end
```

Or somewhere in the view:

```
<%= render :partial => "form_{@user.status}" %>
```

then of course you need to have partials: `_form_1`, `_form_2`, and `_form_3`.

This is only example, in real solution you also need to protect `status` field from being changed by user and add some validations to `status` field, so it won't be anything but 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: Upvoted. I see no reason from the scenario to use anything more complex than this. In addition it might be required to have an action in the application controller to redirect non-accepted users to this action.

Comment: Sorry. That gives me an idea how to approach this. Thanks.

Comment: If you need any other more detailed help, just ask :)

Comment: It would be nice to see and example with model/controller implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but hopefully it will get you pointed in the right direction.

Ryan Bates did a Railscast on this back in June - http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

Comment: Not exactly. I need all the steps to be persisted to the same model, and wait for an admin revision to call each next step.

Answer (score 1):

If you start doing logic as a user moves through the steps, it might be cleaner to consider a state machine.

I've been very happy with http://dev.netizer.pl/transitions-state-machine-for-rails-3.html

Then you can just do stuff like `user.approve!`

And hook up the actions that means separately in the state machine, such as sending emails.  As soon as you get more than 1 or two actions per transition, or have to add a new transition, it starts making sense to model as a state machine, IMHO.